# Is there an error in running test cases on the robotframework ride?

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

The robotframework-ride encountered the following error when running test cases, but the test cases can run normally. What is the reason for this and how can I solve this problem?

```
[ ERROR ] Calling method 'log_message' of listener 'C:\Users\11197\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\robotide\contrib\testrunner\TestRunnerAgent.py' failed: AttributeError: 'Output' object has no attribute '_xmllogger'
```

Would you help me,Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention the version of RIDE you are using, but I assume it is v2.0.8.1.

The error you see is because you are "probably" using Robot Framework v7.0.

That problem is fixed in current development version of RIDE, v2.1dev21.

You can downgrade Robot Framework to v6.1.1, or try the development version of RIDE (instructions at [project page](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE)).

You should try to setup a python virtual environment to use development version of RIDE, but be aware not to run both versions, old and new, at the same time, as they share the same settings and documentation database.

Comment: There are still issues with installing Ride version v2.1dev21, but after the robot framework is downgraded to v6.1.1, there will be no more errors. Thank you！